# .environment-modifier: How can Swift the type derive (from only the path given)?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Taken for example this code-snippet:

```
.environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { /* ... */ }
```

**How does Swift know, to which type '.openURL' belongs?** What's if there are two types with this property?